# How to stop phantom notifications?

Tags: google-calendar, notifications

I've been rearranging the events on my Google Calendar a bit, and I've run into a bit of difficulty. Despite all of my notifications and reminders being turned off, I receive email notifications for the event. I have checked my phone to see if it is an issue of duplicate events, but that is not the case either. As well, the notifications that I receive look at though they are from a similar event that had previously been deleted.

Is there a way to be sure that notifications are turned off, or that an event truly has been deleted?

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sharing calendar with another app?  E.g. If you use apple calendar and share events between calendars I've gotten situations where I've gotten notifications from both.